# Swift -FirebaseDatabase how to count and iterate through children that are only keyIds?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, count

My layout is like this

```
@locationRef
    |
    @---LtFirstKeyUqABC123
    |       |--key1:val1
    |       |--key2:val2
    |
    @---LtLastKeyrUqXYZ789
    |       |--key1:val1
    |       |--key2:val2
    |
    |---address: "123 Broadway"
    |---city: "Bronx"
    |---state: "NY"
    |---zipcode: "10025"
    |---country: "United States"
```

I only want to count and iterate through Firebase `KeyIDs` and not the other data. For eg, the above `locationRef` has 7 children but of those 7 only 2 of them are keyIds (`LtFirstKeyUqABC123` and `LtLastKeyrUqXYZ789`) that have their own 2 children each.

```
var startKey: String?
var totalCountOfKeyIds = 0

Database.database().reference().child("locationRef")
  .queryOrderedByKey()
  .queryLimited(toLast: 10)
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

     if !snapshot.exists() {
        self.totalCountOfKeyIds = 0
        return
     }

     for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {

         let snap = childSnapshot as! DataSnapshot

         // totalCountOfKeyIds = Int(snap.childrenCount) doesn't work
         print(Int(snap.childrenCount)) // on every loop this gives me the 2 children under each keyId

         if snap.exists() {

              // loop through children
              guard let children = snap.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
              for child in snap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                  if let dict = child.value as? [String: Any] {
                      // get dict values
                  }
              }
              self.startKey = children.key
         }
     }
})
```

When it's done `totalCountOfKeyIds` should only equal `2` and `startKey` should be `LtLastKeyrUqXYZ789`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing different entity types under a node is a bad idea for many reasons, one of them being the one you encountered here. I recommend restructuring your data model to have two top-level lists, with the names properties under one of these, and the push IDs under another.

That said, on your current structure you can get the count by:

1. Excluding the properties you don't want to count.
2. Subtracting the number of properties you don't want to count.

The first of these would look like this:

```
let excludedKeys = ["address", "city", "state", "zipcode", "country"]
Database.database().reference().child("locationRef")
  .queryOrderedByKey()
  .queryLimited(toLast: 10)
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    self.totalCountOfKeyIds = 0

    for childSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        for child in childSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            if !excludedKeys.contains(child.key) {
                self.totalCountOfKeyIds = self.totalCountOfKeyIds + 1
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: That’s the exact thing u came up with. I put the address, zip, etc under a node naked locations then just filtered looking for that node. I didn’t add because I wasn’t sure if there was another way. Anyhow thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you send me a link to some documentation that has all the reasons why it’s not a good idea to mix data types under one node. I was thinking about what you said and several of my nodes are structured that way. Nothing I ever encountered said not to do that. I wish I knew that before 

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure